# Знаки препинания для выделения слова "зачем"

Tags: пунктуация

Как верно расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении? Какими знаками выделять слово "зачем":

> Стакан чая бесполезен: если из него невозможно пить, зачем нужен этот
>   стакан.

Comment: А какие у Вас предложения? Почему Вы решили, что его надо выделить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки препинания расставлены в целом верно. Только точка в конце, на мой взгляд, должна быть заменена на вопросительный или восклицательный знак или хотя бы на многоточие (нужно как-то передать эмоции):

**Стакан чая бесполезен: если из него невозможно пить, зачем нужен этот стакан?**

Слово *зачем* само по себе не требует никаких знаков препинания. В данном предложении запятая перед словом *зачем* нужна, так как она отделяет придаточное предложение с союзом *если* ("если из него невозможно пить").

О знаках препинания в сложноподчинённом предложении смотри [здесь](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/751-24_znaki_prepinaniya_v_slozhnopodchinennom_predlozhenii_s_odnim_pridatochnym.html).